# Unable to create Play framework web application using sbt?

Tags: playframework, sbt

I've followed this [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/NewApplication) to create a new Play application, myFirstApp, using sbt. I've a `build.sbt` in the myFirstApp folder and a `plugins.sbt` in `myFirstApp/project` folder.

However, I'm getting the following error on executing `sbt` from myFirstApp,

```
~/ScalaWorkspace/myFirstApp/build.sbt:7: error: not found: value playScalaSettings
playScalaSettings
^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? i
[warn] Ignoring load failure: no project loaded.
```

How do I solve this problem?

**UPDATE 1:** Getting this error:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: play#routes-compiler_2.9.2;2.1.1: not found
[warn]  :: play#templates-compiler_2.9.2;2.1.1: not found
[warn]  :: play#console_2.9.2;2.1.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: play#sbt-link;2.1.1!sbt-link.jar
[warn]  :: play#play-exceptions;2.1.1!play-exceptions.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: play#routes-compiler_2.9.2;2.1.1: not found
unresolved dependency: play#templates-compiler_2.9.2;2.1.1: not found
unresolved dependency: play#console_2.9.2;2.1.1: not found
download failed: play#sbt-link;2.1.1!sbt-link.jar
download failed: play#play-exceptions;2.1.1!play-exceptions.jar
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was my first `sbt`-centric Play development so bear with me if the solution doesn't meet acceptable quality standards.

I followed the section **Create a new application without having Play installed** in the document [Creating a new application](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/NewApplication) and ended up with the following files.

`build.sbt` is as described in the document.

```
import play.Project._

name := "My first application"

version := "1.0"

playScalaSettings
```

I then created `project/build.properties` as it's a recommended approach to have reproducible builds - the version of sbt is known and fixed.

```
sbt.version=0.13.0
```

I modified `project/plugins.sbt` to be as follows:

```
// Typesafe snapshots
resolvers += "Typesafe Snapshots" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/"

resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.0-RC2")
```

With the files in the project, I could execute `sbt` and have the project's prompt.

```
jacek:~/sandbox/myFirstApp
$ sbt
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/jacek/sandbox/myFirstApp/project
[info] Set current project to My first application (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/myFirstApp/)
[My first application] $ run
...lots of [SUCCESSFUL ]'s

--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

Comment: I've noticed you use play#..._2.9.2;... dependencies so it differs from what I offered in my response - you should be using `com.typesafe.play` in `addSbtPlugin`. The version `2.9.2` is also a warning sign that you're using another version of Scala - make sure you use sbt 0.13.0.

Comment: Jacek, On checking thoroughly, I noticed that I was using sbt 0.12.3. On trying with sbt 0.13.0, it worked. Thanks a lot.